# How to make JavaFX ListProperty modifiable only through custom methods

Tags: data-binding, javafx, unmodifiable, listproperty

I have a private list and I don't want that it can be modified from outside in general. Just adding from outside is allowed and only if the object is valid. Therefore I used to write it like this:

```
private List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Object> getList()
{
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}

public void addObject(Object object)
{
    if (isObjectValid(object)) //any validation
        list.add(object);
}
```

Now for JavaFX purposes I turn the list to a property:

```
private ListProperty<Object> list =
               new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
```

To profit from the benefits of an property like data binding and the `ListChangeListener` I have to provide the property to the outer world. But then access to all methods of a list is provided, too. (To use a ReadOnlyListProperty has no effect since the list instance itself will never change.) What can I do to achieve all goals:

- private ListProperty
- ListChangeListener can be added from outside
- Usable for binding dependencies from outside (the *create* methods form class Bindings)
- No modifying of the property or list instance itself
- Modifying of list content from outside only through my own methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but try:

```
private ListProperty<Object> list = new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());

private ReadOnlyListWrapper<Object> publicList = new ReadOnlyListWrapper<>();
```

and in the constructor:

```
publicList.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(
    () -> FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(list.getValue()),
    list));
```

then your accessor method is

```
public ReadOnlyListProperty<Object> getList() {
    return publicList.getReadOnlyProperty();
}
```

Comment: Great, I've tested it and it seems to fulfill all goals! However, your bind method misses a bracket and the method from FXCollections is called unmodifiableObservableList().

Comment: If this solves your requirement, please remember to mark it as a solution.

Comment: @Arceus Thanks for pointing out the typos (as you can guess I just typed it in directly): now fixed.